# SQL- duplication of values from a query

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming that company name and product name are primary keys at their relation, I don't understand how come that name of company can't be repeated in this query:

```
     SELECT  Company.name
     FROM    Company, Product
     WHERE   Company.name=Product.maker
              AND  Product.name  IN
                         (SELECT Purchase.product
                           FROM   Purchase
                           WHERE Purchase.buyer = ‘Joe Blow‘);
```

If S company made two products X,Y which Joe Blow bought them both, so at the beginning we would make a cartesian product for the condition "Company.name=Product.maker": S-X, S-Y and for both, Product.name is in the set which compute, and therefor S should be output twice, no?

Comment: Yes. What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: Why on earth people want to write such queries, just use joins properly?

Comment: @Ben Beli: Then your lecturer is either wrong, or he left out a "Group By Company.name" by accident.

Comment: - or a DISTINCT in the SELECT clause.

Comment: well if you have database which using sets (where no duplicates allowed), then you'll have no repeated company

Comment: Do we need a tag for "stupid professor tricks" ?

Comment: Are you saying that when you run this query, it shows `S` twice but you only want it shown once? Or are you saying that when you run this query, it shows `S` once but you think it should be shown twice? Tell us your expected result and your actual result.

Comment: I'm saying that it was claimed that in case product name and company name are primary keys at their relations, S would be output only once, and I could not understand why, buy this claim is wrong I see.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your table structure or an error message, I can't really tell what's wrong. Your syntax appears to be correct.

However, your query could be improved by using better joins:

```
SELECT
    c.name
FROM
    Company c
    INNER JOIN Product prod
        ON c.name = prod.maker
    INNER JOIN Purchase pch
        ON prod.name = pch.product
WHERE
    pch.buyer = 'Joe Blow'
```

I would recommend using explicit joins (`INNER JOIN` with an `ON` join condition) instead of implicit joins (comma-separated tables and join conditions in the `WHERE` clause) because it makes it clearer exactly how the tables are joined together.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, in majority of RDBMS your query will return two 'S'.

you can try it yourself here [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64881/2)

you can put distinct to have no duplicates

```
 SELECT  distinct Company.name
 FROM    Company, Product
 WHERE   Company.name=Product.maker
          AND  Product.name  IN
                     (SELECT Purchase.product
                       FROM   Purchase
                       WHERE Purchase.buyer = 'Joe Blow')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's OK that returns two S, because you projected company names from a query that returns company and products, each row of this query is unique but when you project some columns they maybe not unique, or can use DISTINCT